# How to limit the params types in typescript function

Tags: typescript

Suppose a function try to assign a new value of a object

```
function foo<T extends Record<string, number>, K extends keyof T>(
  target: T,
  property: K, 
  value: number
) {
  target[property] = value
}
```

but ts give me an error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'.

I think the reason make this doesn't work is the limitation of `extends`.

```
type a = Record<string, number>
type b = (() => void) & a

// c = true
type c = b extends a ? true : false
```

so `T[K]` is not equal `number`.

any workarounds to make the function work?

---

Comment: It's not a limitation of `extends`. `extends` just checks if the left operand is assignable to the right. So, `string extends string | number` is true, but `string | number extends string` is false. You should probably just cast `value` to `T[K]` or `any`. Workarounds for this are a lot more complicated and unnecessary when you can just type 7 characters to solve it.

Comment: yep, I think cast `value` to `T[K]` is a right way, thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you've already constrained:

- `T` to `Record<string, number>`, and
- `K` to `keyof T`

then any value for `T[K]` must be `number`, so just use `T[K]` for the type of the `value` parameter:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVRBTAHlbMAEwGdEAlbCOAJyLRKhpjAHMAaRMEAWwCNsNAHycA0jnyFSiANbYAnnGCIMQgBQAoRIigBDGq2xQAXCvZbEABxpxLgqPNOjOFgG66ANiGymMAbVEAXXMASkQAbws9AyM-a1t7eUDEAF5Edy9sAG4NAF8NIA)

```ts
function foo<T extends Record<string, number>, K extends keyof T>(
  target: T,
  property: K, 
  value: T[K],
) {
  target[property] = value;
}
```

The IntelliSense quick info suggestions in the playground show that TS infers the type to be `number`:

[image: ts-playground]